# How can I analyze "win rate" over time (i.e. on/off data over time)?

Tags: time-series, binary-data

I have a series of data points that consist of 1) a time, and 2) a win or a loss.  I would like to be able to determine the aggregate win rate for particular time periods, and graph it.

For instance, let's say I am dealing with boxers.  I would like to be able to say the boxer Bill tends to peak in boxing matches around the 30 mark, with a win rate of 70%, and tends to fall off around the 40 minute mark, with a win rate of 40%.

What statistical methods or tools should I use to get insight into this?

Comment: Some "magic words" that may be helpful to you are *survival analysis*. David's answer can be viewed as a somewhat rudimentary approach to this.

Comment: @cardinal Survival analysis seems to have two states, a start state, and a second, absorbing state. For present purposes those two states might be called "still in the game" and "not still in the game". Here we have two 'not still in the game' possibilities (win and loss). Were you suggesting a multiple-decrement type model (more than one way of leaving the study) or were you thinking of treating 'loss' more like a censored observation ('they might have won if they'd hung in there')?

Comment: Hi, @Glen_b. Somehow, I missed your comment when it was originally made. Yes, I was referring to survival analysis more generally. For example, a *competing risks* model may be appropriate, and even the simpler case of treating loss as a censored event could be ok in certain cases. In fact, as I'm sure you know, this is how many (independent) competing-risks models would be fit: For estimating the survival function for a particular event, one essentially treats the time to the given event as observed, with time to any other event being treated as censored; the likelihood factors in this way.

Comment: @cardinal - Ah, yes, thanks, 'competing risks' is exactly the term I was trying to dredge up from memory (before falling back on multiple decrement as the nearest term I could manage to bring to mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build two histograms: one for the duration of boxing matches, and another binning duration for only those matches where the boxer won (making sure that they are binned the same way). Divide the counts in the second histogram by the counts in the first histogram to calculate the probability that the boxer wins a match that ended within that bin.

```
set.seed(123)
ngames=100
times = rgeom(ngames, .05)
wins = sample(c(0,1), ngames, replace=T, prob = c(.7,.3))
bins = hist(times, breaks=10)
bins2 = hist(times[wins==T], breaks=10)

plot(bins$breaks[-1], bins2$counts/bins$counts, type='l')
```

[image]

You might also be interested in examining the cumulative probability, which will give the probability that the fighter will win given that the match goes at least as long as a particular time.

```
plot(bins2$breaks, cumsum(c(0,bins2$counts)/ngames), type='l'
    ,xlab="time"
    ,ylab="Cumulative Probability"
     )
```

The end point of this second graph is the fighter's overall win/loss percentage for all games.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this!  What library/tool are you using in this example?  I work mostly in python, but hopefully I can find a port.

Comment: This example is in R, but it should be easy to generalize to python. If you're feeling lazy, take a look at numpy.histogram http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: Upon doing some research on histograms and binning, I believe this is actually what I was already doing using a custom Python script.  My issue is that this doesn't take into account the weight of multiple occurrences.

For instance, I might have only 2 games at time 40 that give him a 100% win rate, with 30 games at time 60 that give a more realistic 40% win rate.  I'm looking for some way to only "bend" the line slightly for those occurrences.  Presumably this would result in a more smooth line.

Comment: Instead of "bending" your values away from your calculated probabilities (which are accurate given your data) you should consider adding error bars to your graph to reflect the variance of your prediction. Bins where you have a small sample size will have a large variance, bins with large sample size will have small variance.

Comment: @Dan when you say 'bend' are you looking to smooth the result, so that estimates with large uncertainty are moved toward proportions at nearby times with more precision?

Comment: @Glen_b yes Glen I do believe that's what I would need